# How to update the GPG keyring on a Debian Wheezy server

Tags: debian-wheezy, gpg

I am trying to setup a Dockerized Wheezy for some development which production servers are still on this old unmaintained Debian version.

The main problem I get is with checking the GPG signatures of the official archive repositories.

Starting from the official docker image, replacing /etc/apt/sources.list with

```
deb http://archive.debian.org/debian wheezy main
```

if I try `apt-get update` I get the result:

```
W: GPG error: http://archive.debian.org wheezy Release: The following signatures were invalid: KEYEXPIRED 1587841717 KEYEXPIRED 1668891673 KEYEXPIRED 1557241909
```

Checking the GPG keys with `apt-key list | grep expired`

```
gpg: /etc/apt//trustdb.gpg: trustdb created
pub   4096R/2B90D010 2014-11-21 [expired: 2022-11-19]
pub   4096R/C857C906 2014-11-21 [expired: 2022-11-19]
pub   4096R/518E17E1 2013-08-17 [expired: 2021-08-15]
pub   4096R/473041FA 2010-08-27 [expired: 2018-03-05]
pub   4096R/B98321F9 2010-08-07 [expired: 2017-08-05]
pub   4096R/46925553 2012-04-27 [expired: 2020-04-25]
pub   4096R/65FFB764 2012-05-08 [expired: 2019-05-07]
```

So I update most of them with `apt-key adv --recv-keys --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com $(apt-key list | grep expired | sed -E 's=[^/]+/([^ ]+).*=\1=g' | tr '\n' ' ')` but still getting this result from apt-key list:

```
pub   4096R/518E17E1 2013-08-17 [expired: 2021-08-15]
pub   4096R/B98321F9 2010-08-07 [expired: 2017-08-05]
pub   4096R/65FFB764 2012-05-08 [expired: 2019-05-07]
```

And now a call to `apt-get update` gives `W: GPG error: http://archive.debian.org wheezy Release: The following signatures were invalid: KEYEXPIRED 1587841717 KEYEXPIRED 1587841717 KEYEXPIRED 1587841717 KEYEXPIRED 1587841717 KEYEXPIRED 1587841717 KEYEXPIRED 1668891673 KEYEXPIRED 1557241909`

Then I tried getting the official debian keyring deb but it looks like it cannot be installed

```
dpkg -i /tmp/debian-archive-keyring_2023.4_all.deb 
dpkg-deb: error: archive '/tmp/debian-archive-keyring_2023.4_all.deb' contains not understood data member control.tar.xz, giving up
dpkg: error processing /tmp/debian-archive-keyring_2023.4_all.deb (--install):
subprocess dpkg-deb --control returned error exit status 2
Errors were encountered while processing:
  /tmp/debian-archive-keyring_2023.4_all.deb
```

`apt-get --allow-unauthenticated update` does not work neither does replacing the source.list file content with

```
deb [trusted=yes] http://archive.debian.org/debian wheezy main
```

So is there a way to update those GPG keys or make it so apt does not check them?

Easiest way to experience the problem if you have docker available:

```
>docker run -it debian:7.11 bash
root@f391e03326c6:/# echo "deb http://archive.debian.org/debian wheezy main" > /etc/apt/sources.list
root@f391e03326c6:/# apt-get update --allow-unauthenticated
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Debian 7 "Wheezy" has been [end-of-life](https://www.debian.org/News/2018/20180601) over five years since May 2018. For that reason, the expired PGP-keys won't be renewed nor replaced. You could use `apt-get` with `--allow-unauthenticated`, but you really should **upgrade to a distribution that is still maintained**. From man [apt-get(8)](https://manpages.debian.org/bookworm/apt/apt-get.8.en.html):

> `--allow-unauthenticated`
>
> Ignore if packages can't be authenticated and don't prompt about it.
> This can be useful while working with local repositories, but is a
> huge security risk if data authenticity isn't ensured in another way
> by the user itself. The usage of the `Trusted` option for
> [sources.list(5)](https://manpages.debian.org/bookworm/apt/sources.list.5.en.html) entries should usually be preferred over this global
> override. Configuration Item: `APT::Get::AllowUnauthenticated`.

Comment: ```--allow-unauthenticated``` does not do anything. I tried deleting the expired keys in case it would let it not try them, to no avail.

Comment: Ok, looks the GPG messages are just warning and not blocking errors.

Comment: Yes, and now you are accepting those warnings at your own risk.